# syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'

Tags: ruby, syntax

really quick i got this error: "syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'", when im trying to use these code to find a value in a db (im just learning ruby).

```
  def load_leagues
    @men_leagues = League.where(kind: 'men').order('id ASC').find_all
    @men_active_leagues = League.where(active: true AND kind: 'men').order('id ASC').find_all
    @women_leagues = League.where(kind: 'women').order('id ASC').find_all
    @current_user = current_user
  end
```

I think that the line of @men_active_leagues is the one giving me troubles.

Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `AND` operator in ruby.

To use `AND` in a where statement you could either specify both the arguments.

```
@men_active_leagues = League.where(active: true, kind: 'men').order('id ASC').find_all
```

or you could specify it as a string

```
@men_active_leagues = League.where("active = TRUE AND kind = 'men'").order('id ASC').find_all
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved in following, self-explanatory, hash composition was wrong:

```
def load_leagues
   @men_leagues = League.where(kind: 'men').order('id ASC').find_all
   @men_active_leagues = League.where({active: true, kind: 'men'}).order('id ASC').find_all
   @women_leagues = League.where(kind: 'women').order('id ASC').find_all
   @current_user = current_user
end
```